# How to run multiple stream queries in Spark Structured Streaming using Trigger.Once() compute policy?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, streaming

Running multiple stream queries using Spark Structured Streaming Trigger.Once() compute policy without application failure.

Answer (score -1):

Spark Structured Streaming `Trigger.Once()` compute policy allows to execute one stream query and then stops the execution even though if we use
`sparkSession/spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()`.

To run multiple queries, we will use the following solution:

```
 sparkSession/spark.streams.active.foreach(query => query.awaitTermination())
```

Comment: The above one is perfectly working solution for running multiple queries in case of Trigger.Once compute policy in Spark structured streaming. I can see there is down vote for it. Please comment or correct before down vote.